# Как прочитать файл excel из response.body?

Tags: node.js, excel, test-automation

Есть EndPoint, который в response.body должен вернуть xlsx файл.
console.log(response.body)
Выводит нечто вроде

> ZS[Content_Types].xml���n�0E%�J
> ]TUE`�ǲE*�מ
> ��(�}'�T�V�3w�YM��+�hc�Ű���Ɔy->f/�(�T0������x4�$��{֢%JR�n�+�b���&f���y.��
> ...

`const buff = await Buffer.from(response.body);`

`console.log(buff)`

> Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 0d 5b 1e 53 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 5b 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 5f 54 79 70 65 73
> 5d 2e 78 6d 6c ef ...

Библиотекой convert-excel-to-json пытаюсь прочитать файл,

> Error: End of data reached (data length = 5979, asked index =
> 204079104). Corrupted zip ?

Причём, если читать xlsx файл скачанный через swagger, он прекрасно читается библиотекой convert-excel-to-json. Также заметил, что размер отправляемого файла с сервера больше чем приходит в response.body.
Подскажите какой библиотекой правильней читать подобные файлы или может проблема в чем то другом?

```
const headers = (authorization !== false) ? { authorization } : {}; headers['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream'; headers['content-disposition'] = attachment; filename=${id}_product-reference-template.xlsx; return this.get(/v1/models/${id}/product-reference-template, { headers });
```

```
get(uri, config = {}) { return this.client.get(uri, config) .then(response => this.formattedResponse(response)) .catch(error => this.formattedError(error)); }
```

Comment: как ваш эндпоинт получает excel-файл?

Comment: сервер генерирует excel файл и отправляет его в body ответа

Comment: покажите _как ваш эндпоинт __получает__ excel-файл_

Comment: у меня нет доступа к коду сервера, я занимаюсь тестированием, и как сервер формирует excel файл мне неизвестно

Comment: покажите как **ваш** эндпоинт получает excel-файл

Comment: если вы хотите узнать, как сервер генерирует excel - я без понятия
я пытаюсь получить файл в коде тестов обычным get запросом axios к API сервера и прочитать его из response.

Comment: покажите вот это "get запросом axios к API сервера"

Comment: const headers = (authorization !== false) ? { authorization } : {};

    headers['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    headers['content-disposition'] = `attachment; filename=${id}_product-reference-template.xlsx`;
    return this.get(`/v1/models/${id}/product-reference-template`, { headers });
--

get(uri, config = {}) {
    return this.client.get(uri, config)
      .then(response => this.formattedResponse(response))
      .catch(error => this.formattedError(error));
  }

Comment: добавьте в request сonfig `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`, [подробности тут](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

Comment: не помогло. так же вылезает ошибка Error: End of data reached (data length = 5979, asked index = 204079104). Corrupted zip ?

Answer (score 0):

Код:

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
const excelToJson = require('convert-excel-to-json');

axios(
  'https://www.wisdomaxis.com/technology/software/data/for-reports/Data%20Blending%20File%20One.xlsx',
  { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
).then(({ data }) => {
  const result = excelToJson({ source: data });
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Результат:

```bsh
$  node src/excel-1/index.js 
{
  'Emplyee Data': [
    { A: 'NAME', B: 'EMPID', C: 'SALARY' },
    { A: 'ABC', B: 1, C: 10000 },
    { A: 'XYZ', B: 2, C: 10000 },
    { A: 'PQR', B: 3, C: 10000 },
    { A: 'STU', B: 4, C: 10000 },
    { A: 'DSDS', B: 5, C: 10000 },
...
```

Подставьте в этот скрипт адрес своего excel-файла. Если скрипт работает - проблема в вашем коде. Если скрипт не работает - проблема или в запросе, или в файле.